# JSON, Python, Search for value in dict based on another value in same dict list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i have a JSON dict list that i want to extract a value from based on another value in the same dict. I have tried multiple ways of getting the value but i can not find anything that works. the dict list can have variable number of dicts, and therefore it doesn't always give the correct answer when use numbered brackets. (['objectEntries'][0]['attributes'][5]["subValue"][0]['displayValue'])

The objectEntries dict list contain more dicts, but I shaved it for size. I will loop through all the dicts to extract the same value.

i have a json:

```
{
    "objectEntries": [
        {
            "label": "test",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                },
                {
                    "Id": 5,
                    "subValue": [
                        {
                            "displayValue": "This",
                        }
                    ],
                    "objectId": 26085
                },
            ],
            "name": "test"
        }
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

where I want to extract the value "This" from subValue.displayValue where objectEntries.attributes.id = 5.
I am fairly new to JSON, so any help pushing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

What I have made so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('fulldump.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for object in data['objectEntries']:
    name = object['name']
    get = object['attributes'][5]['subValue'][0]['displayValue']

    table.append([name, get])

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Name', 'Get'])
```

The value from varaible "get" is usually correct, but for some objectEntries, one or more dicts in the attributes are missing, which makes get reading the wrong value.

Comment: What have you tried to do? Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have edited the post with what I have done so far. I have little to none idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just check for the key instead of guessing the correct dictionary to manipulate?

For instance

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('fulldump.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for object in data['objectEntries']:
    name = object['name']
    relevant_dict = filter(lambda x: 'subValue' in x, object['attributes'])[0]
    get = relevant_dict['subValue'][0]['displayValue']

    table.append([name, get])

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Name', 'Get'])
```

This answer assumes that only one of the attributes entry will contain the wanted key though

Edit:

If you want to specifically get the item with Id 5 each time, you can adapt the filter as follow:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('fulldump.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for object in data['objectEntries']:
    name = object['name']
    relevant_dict = filter(lambda x: x['Id'] == 5, object['attributes'])[0]
    get = relevant_dict['subValue'][0]['displayValue']

    table.append([name, get])

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Name', 'Get'])
```

Comment: Note that if you know that the id will always be 5 in the dict you're wanting to check, and for instance id 3 will be missing, you could check for this value instead of the presence of the `subValue` key

Comment: Yes, the id will always be 5, regardless of if dict with id: 3 is missing. That is what i am trying to accomplish. I am using python3, so I had to insert a list()-function before the filter()-function to avoid error: TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable. However, I'm having a hard time substituting 'subValue' key with an expression for "where id = 5". Tried a few variations, including '5', 5, 'id' = 5 etc..

Comment: I edited my answer to add a lead (not tested). If you want to ensure that you are comparing the same type, you could use `str(x['Id']) == '5'` instead

Comment: You might have an error though, as the other items do not have a key `Id` (they have `id`, with a lowercase i)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help!
I ended up creating a function so I can look for other values also. 
```
def find_keyvaluepair(value):
    try:
        intermediate = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == value, object['attributes']))[0]
        ans = intermediate['subValue'][0]['displayValue']
    except IndexError:
        ans = ''
    return ans
```